# Замена относительных ссылок на абсолютные во внешнем скрипте js

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с тривиальной задачей, которую не могу решить уже как пару дней.

Есть **внешний js скрипт**, который тянет виджет каталога (Названия, цены, картинки и тд ). Из-за того что указан относительный путь к картинкам, они отображаются некорректно.

Ссылки на картинки такого типа ( **<img src = file://...** ) .

Как можно заменить относительный путь на абсолютный ? ( **http://....** )

```
<img src="//website/storage/437.design/images/site/2019/10/2484295/52791_8.png" alt="" data-mgdcwidget-preview-src="//website/storage/437.design/images/site/2019/10/2484295/52791_3.png" data-mgdcwidget-preview-design-id="2484295" data-mgdcwidget-preview-reserved="true">
```

*Пример кода:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function processing_widget() { 
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("file://","http://");  }}
            
 processing_widget();         
</script>
```

Comment: копировать пример в ответ?:)

Comment: замена не срабатывает

Comment: А где **относительные** ссылки? Вижу только абсолютные.

Comment: //website/... - это file://website/..., а нужно http://website/...

Comment: @EFRD замена должна работать как и положено посмотри какие пути у элементов после замены на элементах

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить все сорсы `src` изображения с помощью [регулярного выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
В примере я буду использовать функциональное программирование (в этом нет ничего сверхестественного, просто в данном подходе входные данные передаются через аргументы)

```js
function replaceAllImagesSources(images, replacer='http://') {
  const matcher = /^(?:file:)?\/\//i;
  return images.map(img => {
    return img.src = img.src.replace(matcher, replacer);
  });
}

// В вашем случае вы можете использовать getElementsByTagName
// var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

// Ну а я в качестве примера введу тестовые данные
const images = [
  { src: 'file://domain.com/image1.jpg' },
  { src: '//domain.com/image2.jpg' }
];

const replacedSources = replaceAllImagesSources(images);

// В качестве второго аргумента можно указывать на что
// хотите заменить найденный URL. По умолчанию это "http://"
// const replacedSources = replaceAllImagesSources(images, 'ftp://');

console.log(replacedSources);
```

Теперь давайте разберемся что находится в этом правиле `/^(?:file:)?\/\//gi`

1. `^` [начало ввода](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-caret). Это означает что мы пытаемся найти наше совпадение с начала строки.
2. `()` [группирование](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-capturing-parentheses). Кроме того, что скобки позволяют запоминать результат который находится внутри скобок, данный механизм работает еще и как группирование.
3. `?:` [отмена запоминания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-non-capturing-parentheses). Дословно так и означает "не запоминай то что находится в скобках".
4. `?` [повторный символ](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark). Соответствует предыдущему символу повторенному
   0 или 1 раз

Зачем же я применил скобки для этого выражения `(file:)`?
Если использовать `?` без скобок: `file?`, регулярка будет пытаться найти символ `e`, ну а если применить это с группированием `(file:)?`, тогда дословно это означает: предполагаемая строка **возможно** начинается с `file:`, в противном случае в данной строке `file:` может и не быть. Почему может не быть? Например она может начинатся с `//file.jpg`.

5. `\/\/` это означает: `//`, просто в регулярных выражениях данные символы необходимо экранировать, потому как данные символы `//` принято считать зарезервированными под объявления регулярного выражения.
6. `i` этот флаг - означает регистронезависимый поиск.

Если хотите сами что-то реализовать с применением регулярного выражения, но не знаете как протестировать, вот [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/5gmcHs/1) есть хороший сайт, который наглядно покажет совпадения по необходимому правилу.

Answer (score 0):

Мой пример кода по подмене работает, но код не работал из-за того, что **внешний js скрипт** подгружался медленнее чем выполнялась эта подмена. В результате было найдено другое решение. С помощью loadDataWithBaseURL была указана ссылка на сайт, где были размещены картинки

Код подмены:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function processing_widget() { 
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].src = images[i].src.replace("file://","http://");  }}
                
     processing_widget();         
    </script>
```

Решение:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://site.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```